# How to add new widget category in elementor for custom widget group?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Need to add group widgets where I can add my custom widgets but the code provided in the elementor documentation (https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/widget-categories/) is not working.

I have tried some other codes as well by searching in google but that are also not showing any result. I just need to add some of my custom widgets into the custom widget group.

If you have any idea about it then please share.

I am using the below Code:

```
function add_elementor_widget_categories( $elements_manager ) {

    $elements_manager->add_category(
        'first-category',
        [
            'title' => esc_html__( 'First Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
        ]
    );
    $elements_manager->add_category(
        'second-category',
        [
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Second Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
        ]
    );

}
add_action( 'elementor/elements/categories_registered', 'add_elementor_widget_categories' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Categories are only displayed in the widgets panel if they have widgets assigned to them.*

If you don't have any widgets assigned to the created categories then you can't see them on the panel
[image: You can see it written in the page]